# Issue with select default value of select menu in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one select menu in page2 which will fill dynamic values from DB. Every time when I go to page to I want to select the previously selected value. I am able to get the previously selected value but When I try to set the previously selected value as the default value it does not working. Can any one suggest me what mistake I did? My code is as follows,

```
   $(document).on("pageshow","#saveToDBPage",function(event){
        var selecedvalue = $('#select-choice-1 :selected').val();
        alert(selecedvalue); // This is Previously selected value........
        var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
           tx.executeSql("select distinct Category from Locationlog;", [], function (tx, res) {
            $("#select-choice-1").empty();
            var optionheading = '<option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>';
            $("#select-choice-1").append(optionheading);
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++)
            {
              var opt  = '<option value="';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
              opt += '">';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
              opt += '</option>';
              $("#select-choice-1").append(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
              $("select#select-choice-1").val(selecedvalue); // IT IS NOT WOKING....
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: $("#select-choice-1").val(selecedvalue);

Comment: Make a JSFiddle.. you may need to removeattr selected first

Comment: Thank you Clark Kent It is working. Why can't we use select#select-choice-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('#select-choice-1 option[value='+selecedvalue+']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

or

```
 $('#select-choice-1').val(selecedvalue);
```

**Update:** When programmatically manipulating elements like select fields in jQuery Mobile, once you've made the relevant selection, you need to refresh the element so that the user interface is updated:

```
 $('#select-choice-1').val(selecedvalue).attr('selected', true).siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');
 $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

Comment: @user3300593 :which device??